# Dynamically change UITableViewCell height - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

How do I go about dynamically changing the `UITableViewCell` height? I've tried implementing the following, but for some reason, it isn't working. The code crashes as soon as I load the view controller displaying this table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AvailableRideCell
    return cell.getHeight()
}
```

This is the `getHeight` function in my `AvailableRideCell`

```
func getHeight() -> CGFloat {
    return self.destinationLabel.optimalHeight + 8 + self.originLabel.optimalHeight + 8 + self.priceLabel.optimalHeight
}
```

And this is the `optimalHeight` function

```
extension UILabel {
    var optimalHeight : CGFloat {
        get {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            label.font = self.font
            label.text = self.text
            label.sizeToFit()
            return label.frame.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: the issue is in `as!`. My answer below will help you to the right direction.

Comment: To clarify, `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` is returning nil. So there is no cell at the given path. Change it to `as?` and check for nil and this code might work. I highly recommend going with the "calculator cell" method though.

Comment: I changed `as!` to `as?` and used an if to check if it wasn't nil. It works, but the heights are still incorrect. Maybe There's an error in my `getHeight` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code crashes because of this line

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AvailableRideCell
```

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview) we know that this method is used for optimization. The whole idea is to get cells heights without wasting time to create the cells itself. So this method called **before** initializing any cell, and `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` returns `nil`. Because there are no any cells yet. But you're making force unwrapping with `as! AvailableRideCell` and your code crashed.

So at first, you need to **understand**, why you should not use any cells inside the `cellForRow(at )` method.
After that, you need to change the logic so you could compute content height without calling a cell.

For example, in my projects, I've used this solution

**String implementation**

```
extension String {
    func height(for width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let maxSize = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let actualSize = self.boundingRect(with: maxSize,
                                           options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin],
                                           attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font],
                                           context: nil)
        return actualSize.height
    }
}
```

**UILabel implementation**

```
extension String {
    func height(for width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let labelFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let label = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = self
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }
}
```

With that, all you need to do is to compute your label and store its font.

```
var titles = ["dog", "cat", "cow"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // number of rows is equal to the count of elements in array
    return titles.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cellTitle = titles[indexPath.row]
    return cellTitle.height(forWidth: labelWidth, font: labelFont)
}
```

**Dynamic rows height changing**

If you'll need to update row height, all you need to do is to call this method when your content had been changed. `indexPath` is the index path of changed item.

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't' realize the order in which these delegate methods were called, that explains a lot. With the solution you suggested, how do I have a reference to `yourCellTitle` if the cells haven't been created yet, and you didn't create a cell variable in that method? Sorry for my misunderstanding, I'm very knew to coding.

Comment: @yambo You must have some container with content that you will display using `UITableView`. I've edited my answer and add a more detailed example. Don't worry about the misunderstanding. It's basics of working with `UITableView`, you can find lots of tutorials on the web.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly for cells where the `UILabel` is only 1 line in "height"! For labels that are made to be more than 1 line in height, I'm unsure of how to properly use this method. Is there a way to compare the string length to the label width, and see if the string will become more than 1 line in the label?

Comment: @yambo Method from String extension **already** counts the height of the multiline string. If it always returns you a height of the single line, you might be passing wrong parameters. How do you count your label width?

Comment: I'm doing everything programmatically, and have made my labels to be half the width of the screen using the anchor properties. So since the labels fill half the screen, I passed `UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5` as the width

Comment: @yambo Got it, no problem there. But what about the cell titles? Can you provide some example of it and height that method returns?

Comment: So the cells are being made from a custom cell that I made which consists of 3 labels on top of each other. Data is loaded in from a database, and one of those labels sometimes becomes 2 lines because the string is too long. I printed out the heights of that specific string from the method you provided and it provides a constant 20.287109375, even though some of the labels turn into 2 lines, the console always prints out that same number

Comment: @yambo Okay. Just to make sure, have you checked the line on which you call this method? Is this the same line that displayed in the cell?

Comment: I call the `.height` method in the `heightForRowAt` method, Is that what you mean?

Comment: @yambo Sorry, I've meant, is the string, that you're using to compute height at `heightForRowAt` the same as that you display with your cell?

Comment: My bad. Yes, the string I use to compute the height is the same string that will be inputted into the cell. I use `myArray[indexpath.row].xyz.string`, which I understand to be referencing the specific objects in each row of the table

Comment: @yambo The only this I can suggest is that your string is slightly shorter than your labels width. `UILabel` has its own padding, and probably string itself can fit the `UILabel` frame so it returns a single line height, but when you add this string into the label, it doesn't fit the space for content because of those padding. The only solution I can think of is to change the `height` method from the `String` extension. I've updated my answer and add new implementation that uses `UILabel` to compute height so you could avoid this padding effect. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that UITableViewCell is reused. So getting the height of the current cell can be unstable.

A better way is to have one fake/placeholder cell (I call the calculator cell) and use that to calculate the size of the cell.

So in the heightForRowAt method, you get the data instead of the cell. 
Put that data inside the calculator cell and get the height from there.

Comment: So in the heightForRowAt method, how do I make a `calculatorCell`? I'm trying to implement this method, but I think I'm missing something

Comment: @yambo, give your view controller a property, a cached cell, that you can use to perform the calculations

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you are using Auto Layout, but if you are, you can let Auto Layout manage the height of each row. You don't need to implement `heightForRow`, instead set:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And configure your UILabel with constraints that pin it to the cell's content view:

```
    let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        cellLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor),
        cellLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor),
        cellLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor),
        cellLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

Each row will expand or contract to fit the label's intrinsic content size. The height is automatically adjusted if the device landscape/portrait orientation changes, without re-loading the cell. If you want the row height to change automatically when the device's UIContentSizeCategory changes, set the following:

```
cellLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```